# Луч и кнопка GUI

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, unity3d

Есть скрипт, который при нажатий на мышку создает луч

```
ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
```

Так же на сцене есть Canvas, а в нем - Button. Когда нажимается кнопка, то тоже создается луч, что мне не надо. Как не создавать луч, только при нажатии на кнопку?

Comment: А луч пользователь видит? Он на сцене визуально рисуется или нет? ......Можно, в принципе, в любом случае в начале проверить, типа `if (Hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("button")) return;` то есть если попалась кнопка, то не делать ничего

Comment: @АлексейШиманский таким образом hit не видит кнопку, т.е не пересекает луч почему то её

Comment: @НикитаМедведев каким таким? Там надо использовать `Physics.Raycast`  а не просто `if`

Comment: Что-то типа того: `RaycastHit hit;
Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) {
 if (hit.gameObject.CompareTag("button")) {
  return;
 } 
 
 //здесь действия не связанные с кнопкой
}`   навеяно http://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/CameraRays.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы пользуетесь стандартным UI( а судя по Canvas так оно и есть) то вам поможет  [EventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject](http://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject.html)
Эта функция подсказывает находится ли указатель мыши или Touch-касание над объектом UI. Только для объектов над которыми мышь должна определяться поставьте признак RaycastTarget чтобы они опознавались.
Как я отлавливал события мыши над меню чтобы отключать жесты когда мы работаем с UI.
если работаем с Touch то используем `!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(touch.fingerId)` для каждого тача.
Для мыши передаем без параметра `!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(touch.fingerId)`, будет определять положение клика для левой кнопки мыши.

например:

```
if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began && !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(touch.fingerId)) 
{
    MakeWork();
}
```

Comment: Хорошо, я  жду..

Answer (score 0):

С Юнити не знаком, поэтому в общих словах:

Первым делом проверяйте что курсор над GUI. Если да, то ничего не делаете. Если нет - то создавайте луч и далее делайте с ним то что вам нужно.

Comment: Был бы рад, но не знаю как.